# How to implement an autogenerated, unique Id which contains the Datetime

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an MSSQL table with an auto_increment id. Now I need an additional unique itemID (bigint) which contains the creation date in this format: yyyymmdd###

So e.g. the first itemID would be 20170823001, 2017082300n..
If the day changes it should restart with 1: 201708240001

Currently I implement this in my c# application by SELECT MAX(itemID) and then doing the comparsion (if there are already items added on that day) in c# code.

However the problem is that this is running on a webapi and there is the possiblity that two different queries get the same result for MAX(itemID) and generate the same new itemID. Which will cause for at least one client a exception.

So I'm trying to implement this directly on the sql server to avoid duplicates.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What do you need this unique ID for? And why does it have to have that specific format and behavior?

Comment: Ah sry, as the title says: I' looking for some kind of auto_increment but with this specific format.
So is there even the possibility that the sql-server does the job for me on INSERT INTO

Comment: @emuuu yes, we understand that you're looking for it. However, an explanation of *why* is helpful. As explained in the XY Problem link, often people will decide upon a "solution" that they want help achieving without properly defining the problem that needs to be solved. If you can describe the *problem* (and not your solution of this new unique ID field), an appropriate solution can be suggested.

Comment: Do it in a stored procedure in the database instead of in code.  See : https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/608027/AUTOGENERATE-Stored-procedures-example

Comment: unfortunately this is a requirement i have to fulfill: Every item must have a unique, descriptive number which contains the date and can be interpreted by the user

Comment: @jdweng it does not really matter where it resides, stored procedure has no secret magic.

Comment: @jdweng Doing it in a stored procedure still means this procedure has to be called manually somewhere. Not very good for a kind of autoincrement value

Comment: Wrong.  When you have a multi-user server and need unique items it must be done in a stored procedure to prevent duplicates from being generated.  The stored procedure can block two users from requesting a new number so a duplicate doesn't get generated.  In this case you want the ID and the Date to occur only once.

Comment: Wrong again.  Stored procedure can be called from c# where unique id and dates can be created.

Comment: @jdweng But you still need to call the procedure, Thats my point exactly. The OP wants a autogenerated solution not something he has to call manually. He is already doing that

Comment: You simply call a stored procedure that generates the unique ID and DATE and return the two values.  If the Date already exists a new Date is not generated.  This is no different than doing it in c# except you are guarantee unique IDs.

Comment: @jdweng But you still need to call the procedure. The OP wants an autogenerated solution, not calling c# code or a procedure

Comment: Maybe you can create an insteadof trigger, calculate the value for your field, and insert the new record with the correct value in your field

Comment: Guido : You are wrong and don't really understand the question.  Autogen has to be generated from code.

Comment: @jdweng The OP clearly states he wants an autogenerated solution. Autogen is never generated from code

Comment: Just don't do this to yourself. You are violating 1NF by sticking multiple values into a single tuple. The reason you are struggling to figure out how to do this is because you shouldn't be doing this. An auto generated number should have no intrinsic human readable values. The date and the daily position should be two distinct columns, not crammed together like this.

Comment: @SeanLange Descriptive numbers are pretty common and  widely spread. The reason I want to have it auto generated is to avoid duplicates in the multi-user context

Comment: Just because they are common does not make it a good idea. It would be a lot easier if you put these two values in two columns. Then for display you could put them together.

Comment: @emuuu `Every item must have a unique, descriptive number which contains the date and can be interpreted by the user` But do you **need** to reset the number to 1 every day? If you are happy to loosen that requirement the problem gets **way** easier and more performant.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to generate unique ID for partition, because the built in `identity` generates unique value for the whole table, not part of it. There are alternatives, but the following is pretty easy to implement and will work in concurrency environment.

The table structure is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[DataSource]') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN;
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[DataSource];
END;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataSource]
(
    [RecordID] INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1)
   ,[DateAdded] DATE CONSTRAINT DF_DataSource_DateAdded DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE())
   ,[value] NVARCHAR(128)
);
```

The `[RecordID]` will always be unique as the SQL Server is handling its values. We have `[DateAdded]` column in order to know when a value is inserted. In this case you need to only populate the `[value]` column.

Let's say we have the following data:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DataSource] ([DateAdded], [value])
VALUES ('2017-08-23 00:00:00', 'value 01')
      ,('2017-08-23 00:00:00', 'value 02')
      ,('2017-08-24 00:00:00', 'value 03')
      ,('2017-08-25 00:00:00', 'value 05')
      ,('2017-08-25 00:00:00', 'value 06')
      ,('2017-08-25 00:00:00', 'value 07');
```

The custom `ID` column will be created on read, with the following statement:

```
SELECT *
     ,CONCAT(CONVERT(CHAR(8), [DateAdded],112), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [DateAdded] ORDER BY [RecordID])) AS [ID]
FROM [dbo].[DataSource] ;
```

[image]

Yes, you are not materializing the `custom ID` in the database and you need to generate it each time, when you need it, but you do not need to worry any more for handling the uniqueness of the key.

Comment: And when you put this in a view then the reading is also very easy and clean again

Comment: Will the generated IDs change if I delete RecordID of 5 above?

Comment: @mjwills I am afraid so

Comment: @mjwills It will changed. It will changed if you update the `[DateAdded]` field, too. But, what's the issue? You can perform all operations using the `RecordID` column. You are referring business logic which is not described in the question.

Comment: @mjwills So, what's the issue? You can displayed the `custom ID` to the user, when his `dashboard/portal` is loaded - and if he updates/deletes record to use the `[recordid]` in the application.